# How to get Progress bar work with Ajax Uplaod Image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, progressive-web-apps

My Goal: Get progress % while uploading image to server.

I have successfully made image uploaded to server I can't get my console.log percent show in my console.

```
if (ques_title == "" || ques_content == "") {
        console.log("fill up all the fills.")
    } else {
        // if got image , then upload image , then start to get data and insert into articles
        if (imgCheck != null) {
            var file_data = $('#fileuploadInput').prop('files')[0];
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("key", "60c61b2e38bc472d82b55d61ec29defc");
            form.append("image", file_data, file_data.name);

            var settings = {
                "url": "https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload",
                "method": "POST",
                "async": false,
                "timeout": 0,
                "processData": false,
                "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                "contentType": false,
                "data": form,
                "success": function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            };
           
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {

                if (ajax.status) {

                    if (ajax.status == 200 && (ajax.readyState == 4)) {
                        //To do tasks if any, when upload is completed
                        console.log("Upload done")
                    }
                }
            }
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {

                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                //*percent* variable can be used for modifying the length of your progress bar.
                console.log(percent);

            });

            ajax.open("POST", 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload', true);
            ajax.send(form);
```

My Console only show me Upload done, but the uplaod.addEventListener don't work at all.
Please guide me and tell me what I've done wrong in this code

Comment: Can you try this with uploading at least 1MB image file?

Comment: I upload 5mb also cant work